# solution to use django-advanced-filters in html template instead of django-admin

Tags: django, django-advanced-filters

I'm looking for a solution to using Django-advanced-filters in Django template instead of Django-admin

currently Django-advanced-filters can use just in django-admin , I'm looking solution to get query from user based on conditions